# Require help to solve an Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, exponential-function, problem-solving

$|0.022\cdot e^{-2t}\cdot sin(11t)|<0.01$

Values of $t$ for which the inequality holds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account @marty cohen's answer and using whole numbers, you want to find $t$ such that
$$f(t)=22\, e^{-2 t} \sin (11 t)-10<0$$ If you want a more precise result, you could use a numerical method for solving the *equation*.

The problem is that we need a reasonable guess. We have
$$f'(t)=22 e^{-2 t} (11 \cos (11 t)-2 \sin (11 t))$$ It cancels when
$$11 \cos (11 t)-2 \sin (11 t)=0 \implies t=\frac 1 {11}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{2}\right)$$ but, by the second derivative test, this is a maximum. So, we need to start on the right of it. So , let us use
$$t_0=\frac 2 {11}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{2}\right)$$ and Newton iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.252899 \\
 1 & 0.216374 \\
 2 & 0.215230 \\
 3 & 0.215227
\end{array}
\right)$$

The inequality then holds as soon as $t\geq 0.216$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\sin(x)| \le 1$,
a sufficient condition is
$|0.022 e^{-2t}| < 0.01$
or
$e^{-2t} < 0.01/0.022=1/2.2$
or
$e^{2t} > 2.2$
or
$t > \ln(2.2)/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but if we want to consider $sin(11t)$ or necessary and sufficient condition for $t$. May be numerical solution will be more accurate.